# Set topic of comment-based help example

Tags: powershell, documentation

Is it possible to set an example topic when using comment-based help?

The output for `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Examples` contains subject text in the example heading:

```
--- Example 1: Get child items from a file system directory ---
```

I would like to know if it is possible to replicate this formatting with comment-based help.

I attempted the following syntax:

1. Placing text after the .EXAMPLE keyword.

   function Get-Example1
   {
   # .EXAMPLE Test description
   # Get-Example
   # Sample output.
   }

This causes the example to be omitted.

```
PS > Get-Help Get-Example1 -Examples

NAME
    Get-Example1

ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None
```

2. Putting the subject line first

   function Get-Example2
   {
   # .EXAMPLE
   # Test description
   # Get-Example
   # Sample output
   }

This causes the heading to be prefixed by `PS>`

```
PS > get-help Get-Example2 -Examples

NAME
    Get-Example2

SYNOPSIS


-------------------------- EXAMPLE 1 --------------------------

PS > Test description
Get-Example
Sample output
```

3. Putting the comment last:

```
    function Get-Example3
    {
       # .EXAMPLE
       # Get-Example
       #
       # Sample output
       #
       # Test description.
    }
```

This returns acceptable results, but not as clean as the Get-ChildItem example, as there is no built in separation of example purpose and sample output.

```
NAME
    Get-Example3

SYNOPSIS


    -------------------------- EXAMPLE 1 --------------------------

    PS > Get-Example

    Sample output

    Test description.
```

Replacing line comments `#` with block comments `<# ... #>` did not change the behavior that adding text after `.EXAMPLE` breaks the syntax.

I've seen no documentation of how to set the example topic in Microsoft's documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-7.3
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/help/placing-comment-based-help-in-scripts?source=recommendations&view=powershell-7.3
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aa965353(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Its up to you how you want to represent the sample output in your examples, I like to use `#` to represent it but you need to use `<# ... #>` for your comment based help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding having the comment based help displaying the examples similar to how binary cmdlets do, i.e. `Get-ChildItem`:

```
--- Example 1: Get child items from a file system directory ---
```

I don't believe this is possible with [comment based help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-7.3), note that binary cmdlets don't have such thing as comment based help, their help comes from external MAML files. For instance, if you're on PowerShell 7+, you can look at the external help for `Get-ChildItem` using:

```bash
Get-Content (Get-Command Get-ChildItem).HelpFile
```

These files are commonly generated using [`New-ExternalHelp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/platyps/new-externalhelp?view=ps-modules) from [platyPS Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/utility-modules/platyps/create-help-using-platyps?view=ps-modules).

Though, you can use external help files in your PowerShell Modules the same way you can do with binary cmdlets, the section [**Syntax for comment-based help in script modules**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-7.3#syntax-for-comment-based-help-in-script-modules) explains us how, essentially, we can create our Markdown documentation then use `New-ExternalHelp` to export the XML and lastly, in our Module function we point it to the external help:

```bash
# .ExternalHelp GetExampleModule-help.xml
function Get-Example {
    ...
    ...
}
```

---

As for how you could represent the "console output" of your function, here are a few examples and this is likely not documented because its up to the owner to decide.

```
function Get-Example {
    <#
        .EXAMPLE
        Get-Example foo

        !! Sample output with
        !! foo

        Test description with foo

        .EXAMPLE
        Get-Example bar

        > Sample output with
        > bar

        Test description with bar

        .EXAMPLE
        Get-Example baz

        # Sample output with
        # baz

        Test description with baz
    #>
}

Get-Help Get-Example -Examples
```

Help examples for this function in PowerShell 7.4 looks like this:

```
NAME
    Get-Example

SYNOPSIS


    -------------------------- EXAMPLE 1 --------------------------
    
    PS > Get-Example foo

    !! Sample output with
    !! foo

    Test description with foo




    -------------------------- EXAMPLE 2 --------------------------

    PS > Get-Example bar

    > Sample output with
    > bar

    Test description with bar




    -------------------------- EXAMPLE 3 --------------------------

    PS > Get-Example baz

    # Sample output with
    # baz

    Test description with baz
```

Comment: The point of my question is to learn whether the formatting shown in Get-Help Get-ChildItem is available in comment-based help. I'll update my question to clarify.

Comment: Clearly some technology is used by Microsoft to product the topic lines in the output from `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Examples`.  I suspect that this is either only available to compiled cmdlets or using XML based documentation, but want to confirm this.

Comment: @DanSolovay Examples for a binary cmdlet are pure MAML and I don't believe you can't replicate this for a pure PowerShell function. They're most likely generated using PlatyPS, what most folks use nowadays to generate their help files for binary cmdlets. i.e.: `<maml:title>---- Example 2: Get the last write time of a file or folder ----</maml:title>`. If running PowerShell 7+ you can `Get-Content (Get-Command Get-ChildItem).HelpFile`

Comment: [@Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) Awesome. Please add that to your reply and I'll accept it.

Comment: @DanSolovay I'm afraid I missed important information in my answer as to how you can have a PowerShell function from a Module use external help files like C# cmdlets do. Please see my update, hope it helps.